# add a field to a Django model

Tags: django, saleor

I am working on this project: https://github.com/mirumee/saleor

I want to add a "user_id" column to the product table.
So, I added the following code to line 248
https://github.com/mirumee/saleor/blob/master/saleor/product/models.py#L248

```
account_user = models.ForeignKey(
    Account_User,
    related_name="products",
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
 )
```

However, Django says "NameError: name 'Account_User' is not defined". How could I solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from ..account.models import User

account_user = models.ForeignKey(
User,
related_name="products",
on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Does "on_delete=models.CASCADE" mean if a particular account_user is deleted, the products associated with that account_user will also be deleted? Thanks

Comment: Exactly. Once the User is deleted so your products will also be deleted respecting of User.

Comment: I just figured out that possibly this is a better solution.

from django.conf import settings
account_user = models.ForeignKey(
settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
related_name="products",
on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Comment: settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL possibly is better than User in the ForeignKey

Comment: Yes you can also use settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL